# Accessing a string from all the Activities

Tags: java, android

How I can use the same string in different classes. For example, I have a public static String called message in the main class. How can I call this string in another class?

Comment: by uing that classname.string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the other answers are right.

However, I would recommend you to use the strings.xml instead of String constants, and access it via `getString(R.string.message)`. It is clean, you can have different strings depending on the language and it will be easy to access and change all the strings accessing that single file

Answer (score 1):

You can call public static variable from any class by giving `className.variable`

MainClass.java

```
public static String message = "My Application";
```

in FirstActivity.java

```
private String msg = MainClass.message;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can pass it as an Extra to the Intent of the next activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("String", myString);
```

However, i will just put the string in the res/strings.xml as it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String stringFromOtherClass = OtherClassname.stringName;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Activity1:
public static String message="Hi";

In Activity2:

String newString=Activity1.message;
ie: newString="Hi";

Answer (score 0):

*Static* fields can be easily accessed using:

```
ClassaName.fieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your String like this :

```
public class ExampleClass {
    public static example = "example";
}
```

and use it like this :

```
public class ExampleB {
    String ex = ExampleClass.example;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ClassA

```
public static final String MY_STRING = "any_value";
```

ClassB

```
String value = ClassA.MY_STRING;
```